# escape charaters removal when reading file python

Tags: python, latex, readfile

I have a LaTeX file which I want to display in a form field.
Input file:

```
...
\begin{center}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \noindent
    \textbf{\large Thank You! for Using}
\end{center}
...
```

I read it in python using `readlines()`

```
'\\begin{center}' '\n'
```

... and so on.

I want the escape characters < no '\n' '\'' '\t' etc> to be removed so that the read contents can be put to a form field. How can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115261/how-to-remove-all-the-escape-sequences-from-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

You may use `replace` function which works on Python strings.

```
$> a = 'xyz\nbcd'
$> b = a.replace('\n','') # b would be 'xyzbcd'
```

Comment: I need something to remove all the escapes altogether, simply replace does not work for me. Is there any package, function or like?

Comment: @sandish Have you checked my comment in the question?

Comment: yup Babu, I've read it. Thanks, and guys simply using read() instead of readlines() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if you really want to remove all escaped characters of just the trailing `\n` at the end of each line. This is a common problem many python-programmers have when first reading files, I had it myself a while ago.

`readlines()` keeps the trailing `\n`, so that a simple `"".join(lines)`would restore the original file content.

Just strip the trailing `\n` from each line.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Sample for readlines and trailing newline characters
"""
import sys

lines1 = []
fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")
for line in fh.readlines():
    print line
    lines1.append(line)
fh.close()

lines2 = []
fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    print line
    lines2.append(line)
fh.close()
```

The output will be

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""

Sample for readlines and trailing newline characters

"""

import sys



lines1 = []

fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")

for line in fh.readlines():

    print line

    lines1.append(line)

fh.close()



lines2 = []

fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")

for line in fh:

    line = line.rstrip("\n")

    print line

    lines2.append(line)

fh.close()


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Sample for readlines and trailing newline characters
"""
import sys

lines1 = []
fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")
for line in fh.readlines():
    print line
    lines1.append(line)
fh.close()

lines2 = []
fh = open(sys.argv[0],"r")
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    print line
    lines2.append(line)
fh.close()
```

You could also write `line.rstrip("\n")` to explicitly only strip the newline characters and not all whitespace characters.