# change variable values using sed command

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have something like this in file and I want to change few values

**My file data**

```
variable "my_vnets" {
  default = {
    transit_vnet = {
      name       = "dummy"
      cidr       = "11.1.1.1.1."
      is_transit = false
    }
    spoke1_vnet = {
      name       = "dummy2"
      cidr       = "1.1.1.1.1"
      is_transit = false
    }
  }
}
```

**expected output**

```
variable "my_vnets" {
  default = {
    transit_vnet = {
      name       = "NewName"
      cidr       = "11.1.1.1.1."
      is_transit = true
    }
    spoke1_vnet = {
      name       = "NewName2"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2"
      is_transit = false
    }
  }
}
```

**I am trying something like this but no luck**

```
sed -i "s/\"my_vnets\" { default = \"""\" }/\"my_vnets\" { default = \""NewName"\" }/g"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change json file by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942875/change-json-file-by-bash-script)

Comment: @Lenna, that's not JSON though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In general*, usage of structure-unaware tools to edit structured files should be avoided. However, if there aren't any structured tools for parsing and generating this format, consider something like:

```
sed -r -e '/^[[:space:]]+name[[:space:]]+=/ { s/dummy/NewName/; }' \
       -e '/transit_vnet = [{]/,/[}]/       { s/is_transit = false/is_transit = true/; }'
```

...replacing `dummy` with `NewName` only on lines that start with `name =` ; and `is_transit = false` with `is_transit = true` only after a match for `transit_vnet = {` and before a match for `}`.

Comment: thanks for reply sir , there is one constraint . for example I want to change   `is_transit`  value then whole file  consisting of 'is_transit' variable will be changed. thats why I need to be specific to a variable .

Comment: I don't think your question currently specifies that constraint -- your sample data edits _both_ names.

Comment: ...that said, does applying that edit between the line `transit_vnet {` and the next-following line with only a `}` work?

Comment: I have   ` default = {
    transit_vnet = {
      name       = "NewName"
      cidr       = "11.1.1.1.1."
      is_transit = true
    }
    spoke1_vnet = {
      name       = "NewName2"
      cidr       = "2.2.2.2"
      is_transit = false
    }`              **2**    `is_transit`  variables . So I just want to change one of them

Comment: See the edit, changing `is_transit` only inside the `transit_vnet` block.

Comment: got it . is it possible to to change name of just   `transit_vnet`  block , As I am not sure if it  in future name of both can be same as `dummy`

Comment: Of course, just use the same technique shown above for `is_transit` for `name` instead.

Comment: `sed -r -e '/transit_vnet = [{]/,/[}]/       { s/name = dummy/name = myname/; }g' /variables.tf`    doing this but not changing Name :(

Comment: You're matching only exact `name = dummy`, there, but not with the extra spaces.

Comment: Still I am unable to figure out sir , can you please update your answer.

Comment: The answer answers the question you asked. To edit it would make it answer a different question, which you did not ask. Thus, I do not intend to edit it further.

Comment: sir I am stuck on a small issue . need help   in case of  ***name*** what I will use instead of this   `[{]/,/[}]/ `