# Replace multiple values in json during run time

Tags: json, bash, shell

Old JSON File:

```
{
"firstName": "Rajesh",
"lastName": "Kumar",
"gender": "man",
"age": 24,
"address": {
    "streetAddress": "126 Udhna",
    "city": "Surat",
    "state": "GJ",
    "postalCode": "394221"
},
"phoneNumbers": [
    { "type": "home", "number": "7383627627" }
]
}
```

New Should be:

```
{
"firstName": "Raghunath",
"lastName": "Dhara",
"gender": "man",
"age": 25,
"address": {
    "streetAddress": "126 Udhna",
    "city": "Surat",
    "state": "GJ",
    "postalCode": "394221"
},
"phoneNumbers": [
    { "type": "home", "number": "7383627627" }
]
}
```

Please help me to replace multiple values in JSON file. I am struggling with this since 7 days.

Comment: See: [change json file by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24942875/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

```sh
jq --arg first Raghunath --arg last Dhara --arg age 25 '.firstName = $first | .lastName = $last | .age = $age' file.json
```

Comment: I would like to use variables where

Comment: So do that: `jq --arg first "$newFirstName" ...`