# How to install only the root packages in a Yarn Workspaces repo

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Using Yarn Workspaces it's very easy to install the packages for a single Workspace using `yarn install --focus` when inside one of the package directories.

However, sometimes I would like the ability to install only the packages listed in the top-level `package.json`. I run a linter across the entire repo, and I'd like to be able to install the linting dependencies without needing to install every package needed across the workspace.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on Yarn v1 ([v2 and v3 supposedly don't have that problem](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6715#issuecomment-890310251)) and need to do this in CI, you can do this bash **hack**

```bash
tmp=$(mktemp) # create temporary file because jq can't push directly to package.json
jq 'del(.workspaces)' package.json > $tmp && mv $tmp package.json
```

`jq` is a program for manipulating JSON, you'll have to install it separately

This effectively removes the "workspaces" key from your package.json, so the only thing that's left are your root packages

References:

- [change json file by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942875/change-json-file-by-bash-script)
- [Modify a key-value in a json using jq in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716734/modify-a-key-value-in-a-json-using-jq-in-place)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. As a workaround you can temporarily rename current `workspaces` directory to something different (if you need create an empty `workspaces` directory). Install packages in the root package with `yarn` command. Then you can do whatever you need and when previuos jobs are done replace an empty `workspaces` directory with the real one and install dependencies again (`yarn`).

Answer (score -1):

you can just use the name of the root package present in `package.json` in key `name`, if the key is `~dev` for example:

```bash
yarn workspaces focus ~dev
```