# Shell ping command with source option is failing when executed using JSch setCommand

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

I'm testing short ping test program. If I set simple ping command, `"ping y.y.y.y -c 5 -s 500 "` into `setCommand()` function, it works as designed. But if I add addition ping options, `"ping source x.x.x.x host y.y.y.y -c 5 -s 500"`, I got

> ping: unknown host source

message back. If I manually execute both commands from the x-terminal, the both commands works fine.

I need to make the program to ping from different source interface IPs. What is the difference between two commands using JSch `setCommand`?

1. `ping y.y.y.y -c 5 -s 500`   (working)
2. `ping source x.x.x.x host y.y.y.y -c 5 -s 500` (not working)

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();  

  String host=null;
  if(arg.length>0){
    host=arg[0];
  }
  else{
    host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                     System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                     "@localhost"); 
  }
  String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
  host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

  Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

  UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
  session.setUserInfo(ui);
  session.connect();

  // this command works
  // String command = "ping 20.5.1.15 -c " + count + " -s " + size;

  // this command not working
  String command = "ping source 20.5.1.10 host 20.5.1.15 -c " + count + " -s
  " + size;

  Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
  ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

  channel.setInputStream(null);

  ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

  InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

  channel.connect();

  byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
  while(true){
    while(in.available()>0){
      int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if(i<0)break;
      System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
    if(channel.isClosed()){
      if(in.available()>0) continue; 
      System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
      break;
    }
    try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
  }
  channel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your `ping source x.x.x.x host y.y.y.y` syntax seems strange to me. But I will trust you that it works in the terminal.*

---

The `ping` command probably depends on some environment variable or other configuration to resolve the source address.

The "exec" channel in the JSch (rightfully) does not allocate a pseudo terminal (PTY) for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced. And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on absence/presence of the `TERM` environment variable. So the environment might differ from the interactive session you use with your SSH client.

If this breaks the `ping` command, it's clearly misconfiguration on the server-side, not JSch fault. The `ping` is not an interactive command, so it should work even on the non-interactive session. You should find out what is it that breaks the `ping` and fix your startup scripts accordingly.

To verify that this is the root cause, disable the pseudo terminal allocation in your SSH client. For example in PuTTY, it's *Connection > SSH > TTY > Don't allocate a pseudo terminal*. Then go to *Connection > SSH > Remote command* and ether your `ping source ...` command. Check *Session > Close window on exit > Never* and open the session.

---

Another (not recommended) approach is to force the pseudo terminal allocation for the "exec" channel using the `.setPty` method:

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
```

Using the pseudo terminal to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects. See for example [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

This is a special case of this common problem:
[Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021860/850848)

Comment: Thank you.  now I understand the cause.  I tried to verify Putty connection with "Don't allocate a pseudo terminal" checked, but establishing the connection was failed.  And ".setPty" option didn't resolved the issue.  Now I'm stuck.  How do I make ping command (from various source interface) works?

Comment: *establishing the connection was failed* - How did it fail exactly?

Comment: It hung.  I don't see a prompt.  I was able to see login prompt, but after I typed in login ID, then Password, the terminal got hung.

Comment: Well, so the connection succeeded, right? If you want our help, make sure you are exact.

Comment: Yes the connection was made.  But I wasn't able to verify the ping command because the terminal got stuck after typed in the password.

Comment: Did you enter the `ping` command to the *Connection > SSH > Remote command*?

Comment: Yes I received same answer.

Comment: Yes I received same answer saying "ping: unknown host source."  Since I couldn't get what I want with openChannel("exec"),  I changed my code to use openChannel("shell") now, and it works good.  Only disadvantage is that I have to make my code to send a next command based on result of a previous command.   setCommnd was good for that purpose.