# Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch

Tags: java, shell, unix, ssh, jsch

I have a piece of code which connects to a Unix server and executes commands.

I have been trying with simple commands and they work fine.

I am able to login and get the output of the commands.

I need to run an Ab-initio graph through Java.

I am using the `air sandbox run graph` command for this.

It runs fine, when I login using SSH client and run the command. I am able to run the graph. However, when I try to run the command through Java it gives me a *"air not found"* error.

Is there any kind of limit on what kind of Unix commands JSch supports?

Any idea why I'm not able to run the command through my Java code?

Here's the code:

```
public static void connect(){
    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  

      String host="*****";
      String user="*****";
      String config =
                "Host foo\n"+
                "  User "+user+"\n"+
                "  Hostname "+host+"\n";

      ConfigRepository configRepository =
            com.jcraft.jsch.OpenSSHConfig.parse(config);

      jsch.setConfigRepository(configRepository);
      Session session=jsch.getSession("foo");

      String passwd ="*****";
      session.setPassword(passwd);
      UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo(){

          public boolean promptYesNo(String message){

            int foo = 0;
            return foo==0;
          }
      };
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      String command="air sandbox run <graph-path>";

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      channel.setInputStream(null);

      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          page_message=new String(tmp, 0, i);
          System.out.print(page_message);
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          if(in.available()>0) continue; 
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }

      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    connect();
}

public String return_message(){
      String ret_message=page_message;
      return ret_message;
}

public static abstract class MyUserInfo
    implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){ return false; }
    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return false; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){ return false; }
    public void showMessage(String message){ }
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                        String name,
                        String instruction,
                        String[] prompt,
                        boolean[] echo){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "exec" channel in the JSch (rightfully) does not allocate a pseudo terminal (PTY) for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced (particularly for non-interactive sessions, `.bash_profile` is not sourced). And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on absence/presence of the `TERM` environment variable. So the environment might differ from the interactive session, you use with your SSH client.

So, in your case, the `PATH` is probably set differently; and consequently the `air` executable cannot be found.

To verify that this is the root cause, disable the pseudo terminal allocation in your SSH client. For example in PuTTY, it's *Connection > SSH > TTY > Don't allocate a pseudo terminal*. Then, go to *Connection > SSH > Remote command* and enter your `air ...` command. Check *Session > Close window on exit > Never* and open the session. You should get the same *"air not found"* error.

---

Ways to fix this, in preference order:

1. Fix the command not to rely on a specific environment. Use a full path to `air` in the command. E.g.:

   ```
   /bin/air sandbox run <graph-path>
   ```

   If you do not know the full path, on common *nix systems, you can use `which air` command in your interactive SSH session.
2. Fix your startup scripts to set the `PATH` the same for both interactive and non-interactive sessions.
3. Try running the script explicitly via login shell (use `--login` switch with common *nix shells):

   ```
   bash --login -c "air sandbox run sandbox run <graph-path>"
   ```
4. If the command itself relies on a specific environment setup and you cannot fix the startup scripts, you can change the environment in the command itself. Syntax for that depends on the remote system and/or the shell. In common *nix systems, this works:

   ```
   String command="PATH=\"$PATH;/path/to/air\" && air sandbox run <graph-path>";
   ```
5. Another (not recommended) approach is to force the pseudo terminal allocation for the "exec" channel using the `.setPty` method:

   ```
   Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
   ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
   ```

   Using the pseudo terminal to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects. See for example [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

For a similar issues, see

- [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch even with setPty enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44386496/850848)
- [Commands executed using JSch behaves differently than in SSH terminal (bypasses confirm prompt message of "yes/"no")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41985191/850848)
- [JSch: Is there a way to expose user environment variables to "exec" channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46349113/850848)
- [Command (.4gl) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.RunCommand fails with "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46350481/850848)

Comment: Ah.Thanks, that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to find out where "air" resides with

```
whereis air
```

and then use this outcome.

something like

```
/usr/bin/air sandbox run graph
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ~/.ssh/environment file to set your AB_HOME and PATH variables.