# Commands executed using JSch behaves differently than in SSH terminal (bypasses confirm prompt message of "yes/"no")

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

Note: I log into a device, not a computer, so I login to configuration mode (instead of non configuration mode).

I am using JSch library in Java, to login with an SSH protocol. I login like this:

```
channel = con.openChannel("shell");
channel.connect();
```

In some cases, when I send through the shell a command that needs `su` (configuration mode) permissions (change configuration), this code bypasses the prompt confirmation message of - this may prevent other users from changing configuration. While if I enter the command manually with SSH client/terminal, I have to enter yes for confirmation.

Does anyone have any idea why?
Thanks.

[[image: manual shell session]]

When I log in through JSch I can do the configuration commands even, when the I don't insert "yes" to the array of commands to be executed.

Comment: this may be related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634152/jsch-shellchannel-inputing-confirm-message-doesnt-work

Comment: Your edit did not clarify anything to me. Maybe a screenshot or a transcript of an interactive SSH session may clarify what you need.

Comment: i hope i am clearer now...

Comment: Yes, but what's the problem actually? If you want to automate the command, why do you mind that you are not bothered with a confirmation prompt?

Comment: It is Ok for me (even better) that it behaves like this, but i still would prefer to understand the behaviour. in a different note, i login as "shell", not as "exec".

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the JSch does not request PTY (pseudo-terminal).

That can cause some commands to behave differently than in an interactive SSH terminal.

You can override this using the [`ChannelSession.setPty`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPty-boolean-).

---

If the above does not help, see also similar questions:

- [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021860/850848)
- [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch even with setPty enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44386496/850848)