# Not able to execute a .csh script using jsch library - Exit 1

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh, jsch

Im trying to use Jsch to execute a .csh script on a remote server. I am able to execute commands like cp, mv and ls. But when I try to execute a script that internally references some environment variables, the script is exiting with status 1. There is an INTERNAL_ENV_VARIABLE referenced inside script.sh that is not accessible when i run using exec. Is there some way I can run the .csh  script from exec  that will take care of this dependency ?

Using the shell instead of exec is not an option as there are multiple authentication levels when we open a shell and would make the test framework we are developing, dependent on multiple credentials.

Commands I am calling to navigate to the script directory and execute the script.

```
util.executeCommand(session,"cd " + script directory+";"+"./script.csh");
```

console output

```
com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream@4bff64c2
INTERNAL_ENV_VARIABLE: Undefined variable.
exit-status: 1
```

Method to Execute the Command   : executeCommand

```
public int executeCommand(Session session, String script) throws JSchException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Execute Script " + script);

    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec)channelExec).setPty(true);
    InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
    channelExec.setInputStream(null);
    channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
    channelExec.setCommand(script);
    channelExec.connect();

    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          System.out.println(channelExec.getErrStream());
            if (i < 0)
                break;
           System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if (channelExec.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channelExec.getExitStatus());

            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            System.out.println(ee);
        }
    }

    channelExec.disconnect();
    return channelExec.getExitStatus();


}
```

Method to Create a Session  : createSession

```
public Session createSession(String user, String  host, int Port, String Password) throws JSchException { 
        JSch jsch = new JSch(); 

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, Port); 
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 

        session.setPassword(Password);
        session.connect(5000);
        System.out.println(session.isConnected());
        return session; 
      }
}
```

Comment: For your new problem, see [JSch: Is there a way to expose user environment variables to “exec” channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350885/850848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
util.executeCommand(session,"cd " + script directory);
util.executeCommand(session,"ls "+"script.csh"+" && exit 0 || exit 1" );
util.executeCommand(session,"./script.csh");
```

Each of these command invocations will run independently of the others. Notably, each command will start with the same working directory--probably the home directory of whatever user you used to log in--and the `cd` command that you invoke first won't have any effect on the other commands that you run.

If you want to string together a sequence of commands, you have to run them in one invocation:

```
util.executeCommand(session, "cd /some/directory && ./script.csh");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains why the ls command was not working. But the script still isn't getting executed. I will edit the question to reflect this. Thanks a lot for the response.