# Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to run `sesu` command in Unix server from Python with the help of Paramiko `exec_command`. However when I am running this command `exec_command('sesu test')`, I am getting

> sh: sesu:  not found

When I am running simple `ls` command it giving me desired output. Only with `sesu` command it is not working fine.

This is how my code looks like:

```
import paramiko

host = host
username = username
password = password
port = port

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('sesu test')
stdin.write('Password')
stdin.flush()
outlines=stdout.readlines()
resp=''.join(outlines)
print(resp)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `SSHClient.exec_command` by default does not run shell in "login" mode and does not allocate a pseudo terminal for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced, than in your regular interactive SSH session (particularly for non-interactive sessions, `.bash_profile` is not sourced). And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on an absence/presence of `TERM` environment variable.

Possible solutions (in preference order):

1. Fix the command not to rely on a specific environment. Use a full path to `sesu` in the command. E.g.:

   ```
   /bin/sesu test
   ```

   If you do not know the full path, on common *nix systems, you can use `which sesu` command in your interactive SSH session.
2. Fix your startup scripts to set the `PATH` the same for both interactive and non-interactive sessions.
3. Try running the script explicitly via login shell (use `--login` switch with common *nix shells):

   ```
   bash --login -c "sesu test"
   ```
4. If the command itself relies on a specific environment setup and you cannot fix the startup scripts, you can change the environment in the command itself. Syntax for that depends on the remote system and/or the shell. In common *nix systems, this works:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH;/path/to/sesu" && sesu test
   ```
5. Another (not recommended) approach is to force the pseudo terminal allocation for the "exec" channel using the `get_pty` parameter:

   ```
   stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('sesu test', get_pty=True)
   ```

   Using the pseudo terminal to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects. See for example [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

You may have a similar problem with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and locating shared objects.

---

See also:

- [Environment variable differences when using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/850848)
- [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021860/850848)

Comment: You should probably recommend `command -V` instead of `which`. There aren't many systems where `which` is plain wrong anymore; but why risk it when there is a safe POSIX replacement?