# execute a command from remotedly using paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, paramiko

I have board server, in which i want to execute a gstreamer command from parmiko which will take the input file as a argument

this one is  working

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('ls')
```

want to execute below command but not working

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('gst_app /media/card/pipeline.cfg')
```

**want to execute a gst_app /media/card/pipeline.cfg command  from ssh_client.exec_command**

can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

If a command does not work, start by reading its error output.

Use `stderr.readlines()` for that.

---

Quite often the error is *"<command> not found"*. For that see
[Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848)

Comment: using the absolute path it is working thanks @Martin Prikryl