# How to set Java home in JSch to execute a command?

Tags: java, ssh, environment-variables, jsch

I'm using Jcraft JSch to ssh into a remote machine and execute a command. As it's a non-interactive shell it's not finding Java home. How do I set Java home while using jsch? looking like

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setEnv("LANG", "UTF-8");
((ChannelExec) channel).setEnv("JAVA_HOME", "/blah/java/J8.0_64/");
```

is deprecated?

```
public String sendCommand(String command) {
  StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

  try {
     Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
     ((ChannelExec) channel).setEnv("LANG", "UTF-8");
     ((ChannelExec) channel).setEnv("JAVA_HOME", "/blah/java/J8.0_64/");
     ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
     InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
     channel.connect();
     int readByte = commandOutput.read();

     while (readByte != 0xffffffff) {
        outputBuffer.append((char) readByte);
        readByte = commandOutput.read();
     }

     channel.disconnect();
  } catch (IOException ioX) {
     logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
     return null;
  } catch (JSchException jschX) {
     logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
     return null;
  }

  return outputBuffer.toString();
}
```

Error I'm getting while executing a command

> JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ChannelExec.setEnv`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setEnv-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) on JSch side probably works. But assuming you are connecting to an OpenSSH server, the server must be explicitly configured to allow you to set the `LANG` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables using the [`AcceptEnv` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AcceptEnv). What it probably is not.

You can try the same using PuTTY ([*Connection > Data > Environment variables*](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-environ)). You will probably get *"Server refused to set environment variables"* message back.

See also [How can I set environment variables when I ssh login to my Unix box by passing custom arguments?](https://serverfault.com/q/301318/168875)

---

Anyway, the correct solution is to fix your server configuration to set the environment correctly even for non-interactive sessions.

Or as a dirty workaround you can set the variables directly in your command:

```
JAVA_HOME=/blah/java/J8.0_64/; java ...
```

See also [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021860/850848).

Comment: Thanks Martin. Will try to fix server configuration to set the environment correctly for non-interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This got me when I was trying to run maven using jsch exec.

Easy work-around is to use bash to run your command.

```
String command = "bash --login -c 'mvn --version'";
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
```

or

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("bash --login -c '"+command+"'");
```