# Script via Plink in .bat behaves differently

Tags: batch-file, ubuntu, ssh, putty, plink

I have a `.bat` file on my Windows machine. This `.bat` file uses `plink.exe` to connect to an Ubuntu machine and execute an `.sh` script. However, I get different behaviors on the script depending on how Plink is used:

1. log onto Ubuntu directly (in person) -- **script succeeds**
2. ssh via Bitvise client -- **script succeeds**
3. ssh via Plink (by calling `plink.exe`) and calling script from interactive shell (it's a Ubuntu shell within windows `cmd.exe`) -- **script succeeds**
4. ssh via `.bat` which then calls Plink -- **script fails**

The script fails w/ message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libCint.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Other posts seem to refer to installation/permission issues of `libCint.so` but I know this is not the case since the script works correctly in other instances as shown above.

Below is the `plink.exe` line from my `.bat` file:

```
plink.exe !plink_ssh_details! myscript
```

The above script fails when called this way via `.bat` file; again, note that it succeeds when called directly from the Ubuntu or when I -ssh directly into the Ubuntu via `cmd.exe` (using `plink.exe`) or Bitvise client. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the other cases, you are using interactive sessions.

While the Plink uses non-interactive session by default, when you specify a command on its command-line.

Your script probably relies on some environment variables (like `PATH`) being set specifically. Or possibly on an alias to be defined.

It's quite probable that the variables/aliases are set only for interactive sessions. Probably because they are modified in a startup script that is executed (sourced) for the the interactive sessions only.

Solutions are:

- Correct the startup scripts to modify the variables/aliases unconditionally (even for non-interactive sessions).
- Modify the script not to rely on environment variables/aliases.

  Or you can source the profile script, see [Unable to run shell script with ktutil command from Windows using PLINK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44847506/850848).
- Force the Plink to use the interactive session using the `-t` switch

  This is not a recommended solution, as using the interactive session to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects. See for example [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

Some more obscure SSH servers can also behave differently when "exec" channel is used to execute the command. See [Executing command on Plink command line fails with "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48445395/850848).

Answer (score 0):

I had to hack a solution to work around this problem. Adding a "-i" option at the header of the bash script I was invoking from my .bat file did the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

Note some warn of unwanted side effects (no mention of specifics tho...) when using this option. But calling this now interactive script from a remote ssh session (e.g. when using plink.exe from a Windows .bat file and passing inline commands to the Unix box) solves any issues regarding file/directory visibility & permission issues.

Note to plink users: if you're calling a script on Unix via plink and noticing that the script doesn't behave as expected...adding the "-i" may help debug/solve your problem. Again, note that some have claimed unwanted side-effects of this hack of which they/I'm unaware.

Comment: The side effects are mentioned in the link in my question (but only some are mentioned, a range of possible problems is unlimited). And it's even obvious that "interactive" session (-i) should not be used to automate tasks.

Comment: Martin -- not sure which link you're referring to. I haven't seen any side effects to date. Could you clarify the link containing side effects of including 
-i in .sh script headers?

Comment: There's only one link in my answer. And it describes two out of many possible side effects (ANSI sequences in the output and a command prompt in the output).