# Unable to run shell script with ktutil command from Windows using PLINK

Tags: windows, shell, unix, putty, plink

I have a small shell script `test.sh` in Unix with the following content:

```
cd /usr/kerberos/sbin
echo l | ktutil
echo quit | ktutil
```

Its running fine in Unix and giving the output of `ktutil`. However when I run from Windows using the `PLINK.EXE` of PuTTY, its not running the `ktutil` command properly. The output it gives is the usage of `ktutil`.

> `Usage: ktutil [-hv] [--version] [--help] [--keytab=keytab to operate on]
>        [-k keytab to operate on] [--verbose] command
>     -k keytab to operate on, --keytab=keytab to operate on keytab
>     -v, --verbose`
>
> `Usage: ktutil [-hv] [--version] [--help] [--keytab=keytab to operate on]
>        [-k keytab to operate on] [--verbose] command
>     -k keytab to operate on, --keytab=keytab to operate on keytab
>     -v, --verbose`

The command I use in Windows is the following:

```
PLINK.EXE user@server /home/user/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your environment isn't set correctly when accessing your user directly from `PLINK.EXE`.

Check if there is an alias for your `ktutil` command, from Unix:

```
type ktutil
```

A solution would be to define shell variables with the `source` command, e.g. at the beginning of your `test.sh` script:

```
source /home/myuser/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. In my script `test.sh`, I gave the full path of `ktutil`. Like `echo l | /usr/kerberos/sbin/ktutil`