# Executing command using Plink does not work, but does in PuTTY

Tags: powershell, ssh, raspberry-pi, plink, lshell

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to SSH into a Raspberry Pi and perform some commands. I am using Plink to SSH into the Pi over command line. However I have to SSH into the Pi user which runs in lshell. I can PuTTY into the Pi with zero issues, but when using Plink I get an error saying the command I am using is forbidden. I am trying to use `su` which works when using PuTTY by not Plink.

The error I get is below:

```
plink : *** forbidden char/command over SSH: "su"
At line:1 char:1
+ plink -ssh pi@<IP> -pw <password> su
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** forbidden c... over SSH:         
"su":String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

This incident has been reported.
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences when using `plink ... command` comparing to logging in with PuTTY and typing `command`:

1. `plink ... command` opens an "exec" channel to run the command. While PuTTY opens "shell" channel with login shell and only the shell runs the command.
2. `plink ... command` by default opens a non-interactive session (no TTY). While PuTTY opens an interactive session (with TTY).

---

To test the Plink behavior in PuTTY:

1. Enter the command to *Connection > SSH > Remote command*.
2. Check *Connection > SSH > TTY > Don't allocate a pseudo-terminal*.

---

Conversely, to test PuTTY behavior in Plink, use:

```
echo command | plink ...
```

---

Check also Plink [`-T`/`-t` switches](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty).

This behaves as PuTTY in 2, but not in 1:

```
plink -t ... command
```

Conversely, this behaves as PuTTY in 1, but not in 2:

```
echo command | plink -T ...
```

---

Experiment with these to find out, what is causing your particular problem.

For solutions, see [Script via Plink in .bat behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38313389/850848)