# XCode submission using altool is not working via plink

Tags: xcode, automation, plink

I have automation of submission of iOS apps to the AppStore. In Windows Machine the batch file executed:

```
plink.exe -batch -pw [PASSWORD] [LOGIN]@[IP_ADDRESS] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool --upload-app -f /Temp/upload.ipa --type ios -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD]
```

PLink connected to remote MAC Machine and executed `altool`, which uploads the app to AppStore. The code was working before but after I updated both XCode (i.e. `altool`) and `plink`, it doesn't work anymore. The error output is the following:

```
2023-04-28 07:02:57.682 *** Error: /usr/bin/ditto, terminated with status: 1
2023-04-28 07:02:57.686 *** Error: Validation failed for '/Temp/upload.ipa'.
2023-04-28 07:02:57.686 *** Error: The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /Temp/upload.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive. Unable to validate your application. (-20008)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /Temp/upload.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to validate your application.";
}
```

**BUT**, if I execute `altool` directly on MAC OS (`altool` with exactly the same parameters):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool --upload-app -f /Temp/upload.ipa --type ios -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD]
```

Then the upload successed:

```
================
UPLOAD SUCCEEDED
Delivery UUID: *****
Transferred 54415023 bytes in 2.467 seconds (22.1MB/s)
================
No errors uploading '/Temp/upload.ipa'
```

I checked that it can access the file (if I put wrong file name, I get a different error). I try add `sudo` before `altool` - it doesn't make any difference. Obviously all passwords are correct, because if I put wrong password, it gives me another error.

I run out of ideas. Please help.

Why direct use of `altool` works, but it doesn't work remotely over `plink`?

Comment: I do not have a specific answer, but for a start, check: [Executing command using Plink does not work, but does in PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46591648/850848).

Comment: After looking into some related topic, I need to clarify that in this case it doesn't matter if I execute .bat file or just type the command on Windows machine in `cmd` - the error is the same.

Comment: I do not see why should it matter. Have you seen a topic that says otherwise?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I feel stupid after found the solution, but decided to post it in case it may be helpful to anyone.

I used the Temp folder which I created on my Mac OS Desktop to temporarily save the IPA file. Even after I changed permission to read/write to anymore (to the folder and enclosed items), I still can't make it works. The solution is to use /private/tmp folder (alias is just /tmp, but alias is not visible remotely from Windows). /tmp folder has permission to write to anyone from the scratch, so you don't need to change anything. So, this was the issue with "The package could not be unpacked" message. I guess `altool` trying to unpack the IPA in place.

Secondly, and this is more related to my tool which execute batch file on Windows - for some reason `altool` writes ALL it's output to `StandardError` not to `StandardOutput`. This is quite weird, but all normal messages goes to Standard Error output, nothing comes from Standard Output. So, if you try to read `StandardOutput` - you will get nothing.