# Running a command remotely over ssh from power shell

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, plink

When I run this ./start.sh script from the machine itself, the exes run perfectly. But when I am trying to run this command remotely using PowerShell of a different windows machine, I get this error:

**error while loading shared libraries: libentity.so.5.4.beta: **cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I have tried looking for the same issue but was unable to find it.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> plink -pw tpstps iris@192.168.5.58 "./start.sh"

Running comms.exe

Running abc.exe

Running PM2
TERM environment variable not set.
./comms.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libentity.so.5.4.beta: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./abc.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.59.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

start.sh file:

```
echo
echo "Running comms.exe"
./comms.exe&

echo
echo "Running abc.exe"
./abc.exe&

echo
echo "Running PM2"
pm2 start

exit 0
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your environmental variables.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved, I set the source to my bash_profile before executing the .sh file. It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script via Plink in .bat behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313389/script-via-plink-in-bat-behaves-differently)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, I had to set the source to my bash_profile before executing the .sh file. Now, the working command looks like:

```
plink -pw tpstps iris@192.168.5.58 "source ~/.bash_profile; ./start.sh"
```