# Remove of unwanted characters when I am using JSch to run command

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

```
jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(userName, ip, 22);
session.setPassword(passWord);

session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("shell");
expect = new Expect(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());
((ChannelShell) channel).setPtyType("dumb");
channel.connect();
System.out.println("After channel and expect");
if (expect.expect("#") > -1) {
    output = "Connected";
} else {
    output = "Unexpected Prompt";
    System.out.println("Unexpected Prompt");
}
expect.send("top" + "\n");
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("inside top");
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
out.write(3); // send CTRL-C
out.flush();
System.out.println("exit1");
if (expect.expect("$") > -1) {
    System.out.println("finding $");
    contt = (expect.before);
    if (contt != null && contt != "") {
       output=StringUtils.replace(contt,"\"","");
        System.out.println("afterline"+output);
    } else {
        contt="Error in Top Check";
        System.out.println("Error in Top check");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("oit");
}
```

While I am running this code, I am getting output

```
[H[J[mtop - 05:54:39 up 53 days, 15:21, 22 users,  load average: 0.44, 0.80, 0.76[m[K
Tasks:[m[m 443 [mtotal,[m[m   1 [mrunning,[m[m 442 [msleeping,[m[m   0 [mstopped,[m[m   0 [mzombie[m[K
Cpu(s):[m[m  2.8%[mus,[m[m  0.8%[msy,[m[m  0.1%[mni,[m[m 95.9%[mid,[m[m  0.3%[mwa,[m
```

like these. I am getting unwanted characters along with it. How can I remove them?

Comment: This is due to the tty used by jsch which reports ANSI color code support. I don't know the jsch API, but what you should do here is use a dumb terminal with no color support at all.

Comment: Could u suggest me where i should set PtyType (dumb)

Comment: We need to see the code that opens the channel.

Comment: @Martin have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

These are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that are normally interpreted by a terminal client to pretty print the output.

You get these, because you the JSch "shell" channel by default requests a [pseudo terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) for the session. In general, its a bad idea to use a "shell" channel for automation.

But if you **really have** to for some reason, disable pseudo terminal by calling [`setPty`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell.html#setPty-boolean-):

```
channel.setPty(false);
```

But in 99% cases it's a  bad idea. Trying to simulate a human is error prone. The human-interaction features  of commands tend to change (get improved), what in turn will break your code, when the server gets updated.

You better ask new question about your ultimate goal (what do you want to use `top` for?), because you are likely on a wrong track.

---

Related questions:

- [Removing shell stuff (like prompts) from command output in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40142559/850848)
- [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)