# "sudo" command executed with JSch requires password, even when the password is not required in an interactive SSH session

Tags: java, ssh, sudo, jsch

From Linux command shell I can make SSH connection to our CentOS machine using user `ABC`. After successful SSH connection, I can run `sudo` command and no password is required.

```
sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root
```

In JSch program, I make am SSH connection using user `ABC` and then execute the above command, but it asks me:

```
[sudo] password for [**ABC**]
```

I am opening a channel using the following code:

```
session.openChannel("exec");
```

I do not understand why it asks for password even no password is required. Also it asks password for `ABC`, but in my `sudo` command I have specified user `root`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's `requiretty` option in [`sudoers`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) that you have most probably set.

JSch by does not allocate a pseudo terminal for `exec` channel.

Remove the `requiretty` option. That's the only correct option.

If you cannot remove it, you can force JSch to allocate pseudo terminal by calling:

```
channelExec.setPty(true);
```

See also [Use JSch sudo example and Channel.setPty for running sudo command on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968805/850848).

But that's not a good option, as it can bring you lot of nasty side effects. Pseudo terminal is intended for an interactive use, not for automating command execution.

For some examples, see

- [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)
- [Remove of unwanted characters when I am using JSch to run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44276916/850848)
- [Removing shell stuff (like prompts) from command output in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40142559/850848)

And the same is true to `sudo`. You should not automate `sudo`. The correct solution is to setup a dedicated private key with only privileges needed for your task.