# Getting "must be run from a terminal" when switching to root user using Paramiko module in Python

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, paramiko, su

I am trying to automate a task through a Python script. The idea is to login as a regular user and then send a `su` command and switch to the root account.

The reason I can't directly login as root is that `SSHD` doesn't allow root logins.

Here's what I have:

```
ip='192.168.105.8'
port=22
username='xyz'
password='abc'
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)
print ("SSH connection established")

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('sudo fast.sh')
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    outlines+=stderr.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    print(resp)
```

Now, I want to send the `su` command and echo the root password. I am aware this is not good practice but I need a quick and easy way to test this so I am OK with that.

However, when I do this
`stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('su')` and provide the password, I get an error

> su: must be run from a terminal

Can some one help me to solve this.

I am running Python script on my Windows laptop to ssh into a Linux device and then switch to the `root` user using the `su` command and echo the password so that I can run other commands as root.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, as you know, automating `su` or `sudo` is not the correct solution.

The correct solution is to setup a dedicated private key with only privileges needed for your task. See also [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

---

Anyway, your command fails because `sudo` is configured to require an interactive terminal with `requiretty` option in [`sudoers` configuration file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) (as a way to deter its automation).

Paramiko (correctly) does not allocate a pseudo terminal for `exec` channel by default.

Either remove the `requiretty` option.

If you cannot remove it, you can force Paramiko to allocate pseudo terminal using `get_pty` parameter of [`exec_command` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command):

```
ssh.exec_command('sudo fast.sh', get_pty=True)
```

But that's not a good option, as it can bring you lot of nasty side effects. Pseudo terminal is intended for an interactive use, not for automating command execution. For some examples, see

- [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)
- [Remove of unwanted characters when I am using JSch to run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44276916/850848)
- [Removing shell stuff (like prompts) from command output in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40142559/850848)