# Redirection or piping of stdin or stdout is allowed only with -b

Tags: python, sh, paramiko

I have a simple `paramiko` script that connects to a server and executes a command:

```py
command = "cd /path/to/command_file; sh command;"

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.write('test')

lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)

ssh.close()
```

That `command` file executes some things I don't understand much (separated in lines for readability):

```
/path/to/hex_file/hex -h 35 
                      -cpterm iso8859-1 
                      -cpstream ibm850 
                      -pf /path/to/databases_list/database_list.pf 
                      -p another_file.p                                 <--- changed to '-b another_file.p' later
```

When it's executed, it returns:

```
Redirection or piping of stdin or stdout is allowed only with -b.
```

And when it's changed to `-b`, it returns:

```
Batch-mode X requires a startup procedure.
```

There's any idea to where I can start search for that procedure? Or there's any way to permit piping of stdin?

Answer (score 0):

> Batch-mode X requires a startup procedure.

Your question is more about your `/path/to/hex_file/hex` program. Which seems to be something proprietary. We cannot help you with that. Contact the program vendor.

---

The only thing I can suggest for your Python code is to enable a pseudo terminal using `get_pty` parameter, what might workaround the problem:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
```

But I do not recommend that, as it can bring you other undesired side effects.

For a similar problem, see [Getting "must be run from a terminal" when switching to root user using Paramiko module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49213205/850848).