# PHP remove terminal codes from string

Tags: php, regex, string

While processing the input/output of a process created with `proc_open`, I've been hit with the special terminal ANSI codes (`\033[0J`,`\033[13G`), aside from not finding a reference to what these particular codes are doing, they are really messing with my `preg_match` calls.

Does PHP have a built in method for cleansing these types of strings? Or what would be the correct expression to use with `preg_replace`? Please note, I am dealing with non ascii characters, so stripping everything except... will not work.

Comment: You'll want to choose a character set first. You're reading raw bytes. It's complicated.

Comment: @self, If by character set you mean encoding, I always deal with utf8 strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually ANSI codes are introduced by an ESC (`\033` aka `\x1b`), an open square bracket, then numbers (possibly repeated: `*[32;40m`) and terminated by a letter.

You can use something like `#\\x1b[[][0-9]+(;[0-9]*)[A-Za-z]#` to `preg_replace` them all to oblivion.

This works (just tested), even if definitely overkill:

```
$test = preg_replace('#\\x1b[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]#', '', $test);
```

I've also [found this on GitHub](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/blob/master/index.js), and [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python).

Comment: I can't get that escape character to match, I tried changing it to the [\u001b] but I get an error "Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 2".

Comment: `\u` is Javascript. In PHP you want `\x1b`, and since single quotes will still escape \, you want `\\x1b`. See updated answer.