# how to remove undesidered chars using php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I write PHP code to extract from Linux 'top' the server idle value and I store it in $idle.
If I echo the value using php I receive this e.g.

```
98.5
```

which is correct . If I save $idle in a file in this way

```
file_put_contents("/usr/local/st/file, "$idle",FILE_APPEND);
```

and then I open the /usr/local/st/file with an editor like nano I see this

```
[0;10m [39;49m [1m98.5 [0;10m [39;49
```

as can you see it contains 98.5 but it has also a lot of undesirable chars.
How to avoid it ?

Comment: Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731273/php-remove-terminal-codes-from-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: this worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731273/php-remove-terminal-codes-from-string , thank  you.