# subprocess stdout without colors

Tags: python, encoding, colors, subprocess

I am running a command line tool that returns a coloured output (similar to `ls --color`). I run this tool via `subprocess`:

```
process = subprocess.run(['ls --color'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdout.decode()
```

But the result is, of course, with the color instructions like `\x1b[m\x1b[m` which makes further processing of the output impossible.

How can I remove the colouring and use pure text?

Comment: Why open in 'wb' mode? Just 'w' (i.e., text mode) will suffice

Comment: Does the subprocess work? Do you ask about used code page on the subprocess? In this case the ctype is the path for your change.

Comment: Yes, the result is there, just obviously not properly encoded.

Comment: I rephrased the question: It turns out the color output is the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my win10 and python 3.11 machine. Your command runs without any issue:
In my IDE I can't see color, but this command works also `subprocess.run(["ls", "--color=none"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Valid arguments are on my machine:

- 'never', 'no', 'none'
- 'auto', 'tty', 'if-tty'
- 'always', 'yes', 'force'

Code:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run(["ls", "-la"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with open("dirList.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(process.stdout.decode())
```

Output:
total 14432

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 Hermann Hermann       0 Nov 19 08:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 Hermann Hermann       0 Aug 28  2021 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 Hermann Hermann       0 Jan 28 09:25 .txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Hermann Hermann    1225 Jan  6 00:51 00_Template_Program.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Hermann Hermann     490 Jan 15 23:33 8859_1.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Hermann Hermann     102 Jan 15 23:27 8859_1.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You example worked for me. You can also open the file with just `'w'` and specify the encoding:

```py
import subprocess

with open('output.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    process = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=file)
```

Comment: Thanks. What OS do you use? Is it maybe a macOS problem?

Comment: My tests were on Linux. What response do you get if you do `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: I rephrased the question: It turns out the color output is the problem!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue even if I add the `--color` option. Linux shows the color in the terminal but seems to be removing them when pass it to Python subprocess pipe. Is it really just `ls` that you are doing? There are Python commands to do that without subprocess. If you are doing something else which has ASCII control characters in the output, I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965386/7721752 which might be helpful.