# Flask outputs unrecognizable characters in conzole

Tags: python, flask

I've just installed Flask and it's my first time using it. 
After following the demo on the site, I managed to set up the webserver, but for some reason, it outputs unreadable characters

```
D:\Dafuq\SELF\Flask\Blog>python app.py
Unicode characters: љњертѕуиопасдфгхјклчќзџцвбнм
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
Unicode characters: љњертѕуиопасдфгхјклчќзџцвбнм
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 782-294-512
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2019 09:52:35] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2019 09:52:36] "[33mGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

I outputed some unicode characters, and the console prints them with no issue. What could be the problem for the unrecognized characters at the GET request lines?

Thank you

Comment: unreadable? which ones? Oh the [33m stuff I suppose. Those are ANSI escape code for colors in console. If the console doesn't understand them or output is redirected, they are displayed as is, and it's ugly

Comment: maybe this can help, or is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a "termcolor" package or something that deals with colors in the terminal? I just deleted it and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue and wanted to share.
This seems to be a problem with Windows, as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1832).

The following fixed it:

```
import os
import sys

if sys.platform.lower() == "win32": 
    os.system('color')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution taken from [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/1300251) worked for me to remove the ANSI characters:

> The registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel`
> sets the global default behavior for processing ANSI escape sequences.
> Create a `DWORD` key (if necessary) and set its value to `1` to
> globally enable (or 0 to disable`) ANSI processing by default.
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
> "VirtualTerminalLevel"=dword:00000001
> ```