# ignore ANSI colors in pexpect response

Tags: pexpect, ansi-escape

Can I use `pexpect` in a way that ignores ANSI escape codes (especially colors) in the output?  I am trying to do this:

```
expect('foo 3 bar 5')
```

...but *sometimes* I get output with ANSI-colored numbers.  The problem is I don't know which numbers will have ANSI colors and which won't.

Is there a way to use `pexpect` but have it ignore ANSI sequences in the response from the child process?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a not entirely satisfying proposal, subclassing 2 routines of the pexpect classes `pexpect.Expecter` and `pexpect.spawn` so that incoming data can have the escape sequences removed before they get added to the buffer and tested for pattern match. It is a lazy implementation in that it assumes any escape sequence will always be read atomically, but coping with split reads is more difficult.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413525/5008284
import re, pexpect
from pexpect.expect import searcher_re

# regex for vt100 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693789/5008284  
class MyExpecter(pexpect.Expecter):
    ansi_escape = re.compile(rb'\x1B[@-_][0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

    def new_data(self, data):
        data = self.ansi_escape.sub(b'', data)
        return pexpect.Expecter.new_data(self, data)

class Myspawn(pexpect.spawn):
    def expect_list(self, pattern_list, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1,
                    async=False):
        if timeout == -1:
            timeout = self.timeout
        exp = MyExpecter(self, searcher_re(pattern_list), searchwindowsize)
        return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
```

This assumes you use the `expect()` call with a list, and do

```
child = Myspawn("...")
rc = child.expect(['pat1'])
```

For some reason I had to use bytes rather than strings as I get the data before it is decoded, but that may just be because of a currently incorrect locale environment.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround partially defeats the purpose of using `pexpect` but it satisfies my requirements.

The idea is:

1. `expect` anything at all (regex match `.*`) followed by the next prompt (which in my case is `xsh $` - note the backslash in the "prompt" regex)
2. get the `after` property
3. trim off the prompt: `[1:]`
4. remove ANSI escape codes from that
5. compare the filtered text with my "expected" response regex

```py
with pexpect.spawn(XINU_CMD, timeout=3, encoding='utf-8') as c:
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693789/5008284
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r"\x1B[@-_][0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]")
    system_prompt_wildcard = r".*xsh \$ "  # backslash because prompt is "xsh $ "

    # tests is {command:str, responses:[str]}
    for test in tests:
        c.sendline(test["cmd"])
        response = c.expect([system_prompt_wildcard, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT]) #=> (0|1|2)

        if response != 0: # any error
            continue

        response_text = c.after.split('\n')[1:]
        for expected, actual in zip(test['responses'], response_text):
            norm_a = ansi_escape.sub('', norm_input.sub('', actual.strip()))
            result = re.compile(norm_a).findall(expected)
            if not len(result):
                print('NO MATCH FOUND')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#see https://web.archive.org/web/20200805075926/http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php
class AsciiDecoder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = b''
    def encode(self, b, final=False):
        return b
    def decode(self, b, final=False):
        # escape sequences can be split so
        # work on lines 
        self.buf = self.buf + b
        i = self.buf.find(b'\n')
        if i >= 0:
            c = self.buf[0:i+1]
            self.buf = self.buf[i+1:]
            d = re.sub(rb'\x1b\[[0-9;=?]*[HfABCDsuJKmhlr]', b'*', c)
            e = re.sub(rb'\x1b', b'<ESC>', d)
            if e != e:
                print(">", e, "<")
            return e
        return b''

child = pexpect.spawn(command=command[0],
                      args=command[1:],
                      logfile=sys.stdout.buffer,
                      echo=False)

# two ways to manipulate the output from command
# wrap child.read_nonblocking()
child._decoder = AsciiDecoder() # used by SpawnBase.read_nonblocking()
```

- change b'*' to b'' (it's so I can see it working)
- the b'' is to catch anything the pattern misses, so drop that as well