# How to calculate the length of a xterm control sequence

Tags: linux, console, xterm, vt100

I am looking to format text before passing it to stdout/console. To do this properly I need to know how long a given section of text is after being printed to the console, which requires knowing how much characters will not be printed due to them being escape sequences.

On the web I have found multiple [documentations for these sequence commands](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), but there seems to be no **quick and easy** way to find out where a given escape sequence command ends unless I was to parse them. Is there a trick/solution to getting the length of any escape sequence command without parsing?

```
How many characters is this \x1b[38;2;20;60;122m string \x1b[0m in console?
```

Comment: You don't need to parse them in detail, just search for the end character of the escape sequence.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python shows a Python solution.

Comment: I am using node.js

Comment: There are regular expressions in the other question that filter out the escape sequences. I think they should work in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php):

```
$ printf '\x1b[38;2;20;60;122mabc\x1b[0m'  | ./ansifilter --no-trailing-nl | wc -c
3
```

Comment: For portability sake I do not look to use external libraries or executables for this.