# How to show colors in string generated by json.dump?

Tags: python, colors, terminal-color

for example:

```
data = {'\u001b[31mKEY\u001b[0m': 'value'}
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Generated string will be escaped and color codes will be printed as is.

Even `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)` didn't help.

Note: I don't want to use any extra lib for json colorization.

Comment: You cannot print like that, Maybe you meant `json.dumps`?

Comment: @RMPR yeah, sorry

Comment: Is it only the key that's going to be colored?

Comment: @ThaerA values also might have colored text

Comment: @aiven Are values always strings? Or is there lists, dicts in there?

Comment: @ThaerA anything can be

Comment: @aiven I've added an answer. I hope that's what you're looking for. And please thumbs up, upvote, like, share, and subscribe because it took me a little while to figure it out :D

Answer (score 3):

Try (explanation in code comment):

```
import json
data = {'\u001b[31mKEY\u001b[0m': ['value','\u001b[31mVALUE\u001b[0m']}
jdump = json.dumps(data)
# encoding utf-8 decoding literal unicode
colorful =  jdump.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print(colorful)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the find the solution for this problem. I managed to solve it with combining [Thaer A's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10531780/thaer-a) solution and one from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693789/6804632). I will share it back with the community. Simply using Thaer solution would corrupt the json if it has escaped values like:
`"_id": "b'\\xa9q\\xa2\\x14\\xfd\\\\\"\\x90'"`

```py
import re, json

ANSI_OR_OTHER_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?P<ansi>\\u001b(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]))|(?P<other>(?:.|\n)+?)')
def convert_ansi_back(s):
    return "".join(
        (ansi.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape') if ansi else other)
        for ansi, other in ANSI_OR_OTHER_REGEX.findall(s)
    )

def formatted(json_obj):
    return convert_ansi_back(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

data = {'\u001b[31mREDKEY\u001b[0m': 'value\u001b[32m partly green\u001b[0m'}
print(formatted(data))
```

Result:

[image]