# How to remove these ANSI Characters from my output?

Tags: python, windows, shell, ansi-escape

Outut of the stdout:
This is the output of the Stdout, after the command is executed.But I am unable to remove the ANsi Characters at all.
The output is something is like this:

```
[2J[m
]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exeMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805][38X[38C
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[28X[28C
[80X[80C
administrator@ANU-NW C:\Users\Administrator>[36X[36C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C]0;Administrator: c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

I tried the below, regex:

```
 ansi_regex = re.compile(r'\*\[[0-9]*[ABCDEFGJKPSTLMXdsum]|\[[0-9;]* 
     [Hf]|\[[\?]*[125]{2}[hl]{1}')
```

But it doesnt work.Anyhelp, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some context? What does the output look like exactly?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: But i searched the entire, ASCI TAble, but couldnot find, what [80X[80C mean?