# get sub sub strings from python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big string like this

```
[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: a56bb69b-0dc1-4c2f-a0c0-96d1be7c1efe[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating IAM Role my-role-app: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name my-role-app already exists.\n\tstatus code: 409, request id: a3cbed94-1e30-4cdd-b125-548d422ba105[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating IAM policy my-assume-role-policy: EntityAlreadyExists: A policy called my-assume-role-policy already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed.\n\tstatus code: 409, request id: 643d1d64-4b27-43db-be11-5585410c31c2[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating IAM Role my-role-ec2: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name my-role-ec2 already exists.\n\tstatus code: 409, request id: a741fc5f-7638-4489-be09-6f97dddf148d[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating VPC: VpcLimitExceeded: The maximum number of VPCs has been reached.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 0b8e7173-cd27-42d1-8ae1-a872035a8dcd[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m Controller launch failed, aborting.\n
```

Now I want to get sub strings from it like this :

```
1. Error import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.status code: 400,
2. Error: Error creating IAM policy my-assume-role-policy: EntityAlreadyExists: A policy called my-assume-role-policy already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed.\n\tstatus code: 409, request id: 643d1d64-4b27-43db-be11-5585410c31c2
```

and so on.

**Explanation** :  Evvery sub string will be extracted which start from Word **Error** and end where  `request id` of that error is show till then. So same way every string can have 4,5 sub strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting your output with mixed ANSI terminal character codes.

First thing to do is to remove ANSI escape sequences. Look at this answer for ["How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38662876/6760372).

After removing the escape secuences, you should get a `str` that you can split with [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: thanks for this :D I am doing alot of stranger stuff from last 14 hours . thanks again