# Escaping ANSI characters with Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dictionary

**MWE:**

```
yt_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cQSCIWHwRQ"
   
process = subprocess.Popen(["you-get", "-i", "{}".format(yt_link)], shell=False,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()

output = str(process.communicate())   # c.f. ADDENDUM #1

list_output = output.split("#")

for i in list_output:
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
    result = ansi_escape.sub('', i)
    result = re.sub('\033\\[([0-9]+)(;[0-9]+)*m', '', result) 
    ansi_escape3 = re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = ansi_escape3.sub('', result)
    if "mp4" in text:
        print(text)
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=278 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m394\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       192x144 (144p)\n      size:          12.7 MiB (13285482 bytes)\n    
download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=394 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m160\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       192x144 (144p)\n      size:          12.1 MiB (12663186 bytes)\n
```

**QUESTION:**

I'm trying to get rid of the ANSI characters and have tried various regex's however to no avail.
How can I escape the regex characters, and dump the output into a list of dictionaries?

**RESEARCH:**

Looked up and read various sites:

- [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)
- [Python Code Examples for strip ansi](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=strip%20ansi)
- [How to remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in Python?](https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/24/how-to-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python/)

**IDEAL OUTPUT:**

Ideally the print out should look like this,

```
 download-with: you-get --itag=278 [URL] - itag: 278 container: mp4 quality: 192x144 (144p) size: 12.7 MiB (13285482 bytes)
 download-with: you-get --itag=394 [URL] - itag: 394 container: mp4 quality: 192x144 (144p) size: 12.1 MiB (12663186 bytes)
```

However I'd like to dump it into a list of dictionaries:

```
[{
  "download-with": "you-get --itag=278 [URL]", 
  "- itag": "278",
  "container": "mp4", 
  "quality": "192x144 (144p)",
  "size": "12.7 MiB (13285482 bytes)"
 },
 {
  "download-with": "you-get --itag=394 [URL]",
  "- itag": "394",
  "container": "mp4",
  "quality": "192x144 (144p)",
  "size": "12.1 MiB (12663186 bytes)"
 }]
```

*** ADDENDUM #1:**

As requested by @Cubed:
print out of `output`

```
(b'site:                YouTube\ntitle:               53 Thieves - after hours\nstreams:             # Available quality and codecs\n    [ DASH ] ____________________________________\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m271\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       1600x1200 (1080p)\n      size:          245.5 MiB (257452213 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=271 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m400\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       1600x1200 (1080p)\n      size:          225.9 MiB (236852538 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=400 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m137\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       1440x1080 (1080p)\n      size:          179.2 MiB (187938743 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=137 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m248\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       1440x1080 (1080p)\n      size:          142.4 MiB (149281731 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=248 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m399\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       1440x1080 (1080p)\n      size:          132.9 MiB (139365006 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=399 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m398\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       960x720 (720p)\n      size:          73.5 MiB (77038720 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=398 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m247\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       960x720 (720p)\n      size:          67.7 MiB (71014369 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=247 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m136\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       960x720 (720p)\n      size:          51.3 MiB (53815143 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=136 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m397\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       640x480 (480p)\n      size:          43.2 MiB (45295169 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=397 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m244\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       640x480 (480p)\n      size:          39.3 MiB (41227455 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=244 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m135\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       640x480 (480p)\n      size:          30.6 MiB (32083018 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=135 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m396\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       480x360 (360p)\n      size:          30.4 MiB (31899162 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=396 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m243\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       480x360 (360p)\n      size:          26.0 MiB (27215879 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=243 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m134\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       480x360 (360p)\n      size:          22.6 MiB (23719355 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=134 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m242\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       320x240 (240p)\n      size:          18.4 MiB (19244079 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=242 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m395\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       320x240 (240p)\n      size:          17.5 MiB (18399398 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=395 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m133\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       320x240 (240p)\n      size:          15.8 MiB (16552880 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=133 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m278\x1b[0m\n      container:     webm\n      quality:       192x144 (144p)\n      size:          13.5 MiB (14112534 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=278 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m394\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       192x144 (144p)\n      size:          12.7 MiB (13285482 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=394 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m160\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       192x144 (144p)\n      size:          12.1 MiB (12663186 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=160 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n    [ DEFAULT ] _________________________________\n    - itag:          \x1b[7m18\x1b[0m\n      container:     mp4\n      quality:       medium\n      size:          35.5 MiB (37201730 bytes)\n    # download-with: \x1b[4myou-get --itag=18 [URL]\x1b[0m\n\n', None)
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the `output` string?

Comment: @Cubed added the output string, cf `* ADDENDUM #1`

Comment: Thanks for the output! I think the problem is that `process.communicate()` returns a tuple. Converting it to a string returns the repr of the bytes object in it. Escaping the backslashes `\\x1b(?:...)` should help.