# how do you compare two strings that are the same but with different colors?

Tags: python

```
a, b = "\033[0;37m hi", "\033[0;36m hi"

if a == b:
  print('hi')
else:
  print('bye')
```

Can you ignore the coloring in the if statement to make it print hi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693701/202168

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily by splitting these two strings for example:

```
a, b = "\033[0;37m hi", "\033[0;36m hi"

if a.split(' ')[1] == b.split(' ')[1]:
  print('hi')
else:
  print('bye')
```

I recommend this way I find it more elegant and easy

```
#add this class to your file

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    #you can add more colors here
```

**How to use**

```
a = "Hi"
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}", a , f"{bcolors.ENDC}")
```

Now you can compare two strings normally

Comment: Generally, when colour sequences are used, there isn’t a space between the sequence and the text. So this might work in *this* case, but fail in most cases.

Comment: also, you can do this `split('m')` if there is no space

Comment: … unless the text contain an 'm'.  Regex might be a more robust solution, if splitting is used.

Comment: Yeah you're right