# Python - how can I colour text in a list?

Tags: python, text, colors

Maybe this is normal behaviour for using ANSI, but below I have a list of string variables.  One of which I want a different colour.  If I try to use ANSI to change the colour of the string variable, it no longer recognizes it.

```
a="\033[92m a"
#a="a"

list1 = [a, "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list2=[]

for i in list1:
    if i=="a":
        list2.append(i)

print(list2)
```

RESULT : []

Now if I get rid of the ANSI, it works

```
#a="\033[92m a"
a="a"

list1 = [a, "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list2=[]

for i in list1:
    if i=="a":
        list2.append(i)

print(list2)
```

RESULT : ['a']

Any ideas on how to make it work with colours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal)

Comment: Strings in Python have no notion of color. `"\033[92m a"` and `'a'` are just two different string. ANSI color sequences have sense only at the _output_ to terminal.

Comment: Your problem isn't in the colour, it's in the `if` statement; you're comparing the item `"\033[92m a"` against `"a"` and those are not equal

Comment: this should sole yor comparison problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: At a fundamental level, you're mixing business logic and presentation layer; can you separate them?

Comment: Yes I am realising that the ansi is presenting for the output, but it doesn't work to try to save the colours to a list.  I have been wracking my brain to come up with a solution so that I can have a python LIST and each item is a separate colour.  I am trying to work out a way to approach WORDLE with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the colour; it's the `if` statement; you're comparing the item `"\033[92m a"` against `"a"` and those are not equal.

At a fundamental level, you're mixing business logic and presentation layer; can you separate them?

Perhaps something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Record:
    value: str
    emph: int

    def as_ansi(self):
        if self.emph:
            return f"\033[92m{self.value}\033[0m"
        else:
            return self.value

records = [
    Record('a', True),
    Record('b', False),
    Record('c', False),
]

for r in records:
    if r.value == "a":
        print(r.as_ansi())
```

Comment: This is a bit past my learning level, but thank you. I am hoping to find something a bit more basic, if possible.  I am looking for each new item in a list being a different colour when output.

Comment: How should the colour determined for each item?