# Which regex to use to get rid of ^[(B from file in python

Tags: python

In my python code I receive a log file which I want to store so that the user can read it.
The log file contains special characters like: ^[[m^[(B
which I want to remove.

Example line from the log file:
<13>Jan 11 13:14:39 [2023-01-11, 13:14:39.700] fio_start.info:^[[m^[(B: Cleanup started

According to the answer given in this thread [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)

I have used re.compile with different regular expressions e.g. like this:

ansi_escape = re.compile(r'(?:\x1B[@-Z\-_]|[\x80-\x9A\x9C-\x9F]|(?:\x1B[|\x9B)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
new_fileContents = ansi_escape.sub('', str(fileContents))

which removes the '^[[m' but not the '^[(B':

<13>Jan 11 13:14:39 [2023-01-11, 13:14:39.700] fio_start.info:^[(B: Cleanup started

Can someone please help me to find the correct regex to remove also the ^[(B?

Comment: Try using the `re` module in Python to handle regular expressions

Comment: Where does the log file come from? It probably shouldn't be logging those characters in the first place.

Comment: The log file is coming from external and I can't change it.