# How to remove ANSI escape sequences from a string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

so i have this code and i want to make it be so everyone can read it here is a copy of the repounse:

I even asked every ai i know and ever c# developer they all give me something random that did not work so if you can help me i can give you credits on my github!

```
[
  "pl"
]
[
  "[19:37:36 INFO]: Plugins (85): \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mActionUtil*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mAlonsoLeaderboards\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mAntiDisconnectSpam\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mantiRedstoneClock\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mAntiUserSteal*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mArmorStandTools\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85masCMD*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mBansWebhook\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mBetterRTP\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mChatColor\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mChatReaction\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mChestShop\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;85;85mCitizens\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mCMILib\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mConsola*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mConsoleSpamFix\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mCraftingStore\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mCrazyCrates\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mCrazyEnchantments\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDecentHolograms\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDeluxeMenus\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDeluxeTags\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDiceFurniture\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDisableJoinMessage*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mDiscordSRV\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85meGlow\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mEssentials\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mEssentialsSpawn\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mExploitFixer\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mFarmLimiter\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mFastAsyncWorldEdit (WorldEdit)\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mFishCore\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mFurnitureLib\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mGiveall*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mHamsterAPI\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mHeadDatabase\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mInteractiveChat\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mInteractiveChatDiscordSrvAddon\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mJobs\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mLiteBans\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mLiteJoin*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mLoneLibs\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mLPC\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mLuckPerms\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMatrix\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMineableSpawners\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMinepacks\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMoneyPouch*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMultiverse-Core\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mMultyPrestige*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mNBTAPI\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mNoEncryption (ChatSignatures)\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mOreAnnouncer\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPCGF_PluginLib\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPlaceholderAPI\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPlayTime*\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPlugMan\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPreciousStones\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPrisonRanksX\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mProtectionLib\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mProtocolLib\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mPS-Fix\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mQuests\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mReferral\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mSafeNET\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mSellChest\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mSellStick\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mServerRestart\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mShopGUIPlus\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mShopGUIPlusMineableSpawnersBridge\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mspark\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mStackMob\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mStaffChat\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mStatz\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mSuperMobCoins\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mTAB\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mTokenManager\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mTradeMe\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mUltimateTimber\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mVault\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mViaVersion\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mWorldGuard\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mWraith\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mXPBoost\u001b[m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m, \u001b[m\u001b[38;2;85;255;85mzAuctionHouseV3\u001b[m"
]
```

I tried using this code:

```
public static string RemoveAnsiEscapeSequences(string input) {
    string pattern = @"\x1B\[.*?[@-~]";
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
}

private void UpdateConsoleOutput(string consoleOutput) {
    if (consoleTextBox.InvokeRequired) {
        consoleTextBox.Invoke(new Action < string > (UpdateConsoleOutput), consoleOutput);
    } else {
        try {
            var lines = consoleOutput.Split(new [] {
                Environment.NewLine
            }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach(var line in lines) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
                    try {
                        var eventData = JObject.Parse(line);
                        if (eventData.TryGetValue("event", out
                                var eventToken) && eventData.TryGetValue("args", out
                                var argsToken)) {
                            var eventType = eventToken.ToString();
                            if (eventType == "console output") {
                                var args = argsToken.ToString().Replace("\u001B\\[[;\\d]*m", "");
                                string s = args + Environment.NewLine;
                                s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
                                string output = RemoveAnsiEscapeSequences(s);
                                consoleTextBox.AppendText(output);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JsonReaderException) {}
                }
            }

            consoleTextBox.SelectionStart = consoleTextBox.Text.Length;
            consoleTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("(CONSOLE) A fatal error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            Alert("Can't display the console. There was an error.", FrmAlert.enmType.Warning);
            FrmServerController x = new FrmServerController(ServerId);
            x.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}

private string RemoveUnicodeAndColorCodes(string text) {
    string cleanedText = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Cs}", ""); // Remove Unicode characters
    cleanedText = Regex.Replace(cleanedText, @"\u001B\[\d{1,2}m", ""); // Remove color codes (e.g., \u001B[32m)
    return cleanedText;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: @HansPassant What does this have to do with c#???

Comment: @NaysKutzu Nothing, but it provides an alternate regex that can be tried... While it's not C#, at least it's on topic.