# How to remove escape sequences from a list if list contains unicode and non-ascii characters?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, ascii

I'm pulling some [licensure data](https://wd.kyepsb.net/EPSB.WebApps/KECI/view_data.aspx?id=200114934) and placing it into a list.

```
rank = ['\r\n\t\t', 'RANK2', 'Rank II', '07', '-', '01', '-', '2016', u'\xa0', '06', '-', '30', '-', '2021', u'\xa0', '\r\n\t']
cert = ['\r\n\t\t', 'KEL', 'Professional Certificate For Teaching In Elementary School, Primary Through Grade 5', '07', '-', '01', '-', '2016', u'\xa0', '06', '-', '30', '-', '2021', u'\xa0', '\r\n\t']
```

I want to remove the unicode characters and non-ascii characters from my lists and ultimately get my lists to look like this:

```
rank = ['RANK2', 'Rank II', '07-01-2016', '06-30-2021']
cert = ['KEL', 'Professional Certificate For Teaching In Elementary School, Primary Through Grade 5', '07-01-2016', '06-30-2021']
```

I've looked through some other questions that [remove escape sequences from lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115261/how-to-remove-all-the-escape-sequences-from-a-list-of-strings), [remove unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string), [remove non-ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python), and some [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings) but I can't get them to work for my situation.

Some get close but no cigar:

```
[word for word in cert if word.isalnum()]
>>> ['KEL', '07', '01', '2016', '06', '30', '2021']

def recursive_map(lst, fn):
    return [recursive_map(x, fn) if isinstance(x, list) else fn(x) for x in lst]
recursive_map(rank, lambda x: x.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
>>>['\r\n\t\t', 'RANK2', 'Rank II', '07', '-', '01', '-', '2016', '', '06', '-', '30', '-', '2021', '', '\r\n\t']
```

I'm stuck in a rut at the moment...anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting `rank` and `cert`? If you're scraping the HTML page you're probably better off using `beautifulsoup` or a similar library, which has built-in ways to get you all the text in a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something quick-n-dirty:

```
rank = ['\r\n\t\t', 'RANK2', 'Rank II', '07', '-', '01', '-', '2016', u'\xa0', '06', '-', '30', '-', '2021', u'\xa0', '\r\n\t']
cert = ['\r\n\t\t', 'KEL', 'Professional Certificate For Teaching In Elementary School, Primary Through Grade 5', '07', '-', '01', '-', '2016', u'\xa0', '06', '-', '30', '-', '2021', u'\xa0', '\r\n\t']

def clean(L):
    '''Removes non-printable characters and filters result for empty strings.
    '''
    cleaned = [scrubbed(x) for x in L if scrubbed(x)]
    # I use a character not in the ASCII range to rejoin the hyphenated dates.
    return '\xa0'.join(cleaned).replace('\xa0-\xa0','-').split('\xa0')

def scrubbed(s):
    '''Removed control and non-ASCII characters.
    '''
    return ''.join([n for n in s if 32 <= ord(n) <= 127])

print(clean(rank))
print(clean(cert))
```

Output:

```
['RANK2', 'Rank II', '07-01-2016', '06-30-2021']
['KEL', 'Professional Certificate For Teaching In Elementary School, Primary Through Grade 5', '07-01-2016', '06-30-2021']
```