# Python how to remove escape characters from a string

Tags: python

I have a string like below, and I want to remove all \x06 characters from the string in Python.

Ex:

```
s = 'test\x06\x06\x06\x06'
s1 = 'test2\x04\x04\x04\x04'
print(literal_eval("'%s'" % s))
```

output:
    test♠♠♠♠

I just need String test and remove all \xXX.

Comment: What about `\x04`

Comment: I want to remove even \x04.

Comment: `"test\x06\x06\x06\x06, test2\x04\x04\x04\x04".replace('\x06','')`

Comment: Also, string or bytes? Py 2 or py 3? What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: What's special about `\x04`? What about `\x20`?

Comment: I second @Mad Physicist in posting what you have tried so far. Also: do you have other escape chars or only these two? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all the escape sequences from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115261/how-to-remove-all-the-escape-sequences-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: @davedwards I have tried this and it returns test♠♠♠♠. I just need string 'test'

Comment: @ashkus you're right, how about this: `import re; re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', s)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the regex module is the way to go

```
>>> s = 'test\x06\x06\x06\x06'
>>> s1 = 'test2\x04\x04\x04\x04'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', s)
'test'
>>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', s1)
'test2'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all `\xXX` characters (non-printable ascii characters) the best way is probably like so

```
import string

def remove_non_printable(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.printable)
```

Note this won't work with any non-ascii printable characters (like `é`, which will be removed).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
import re #Import regular expressions
s = 'test\x06\x06\x06\x06' #Input s
s1 = 'test2\x04\x04\x04\x04' #Input s1
print(re.sub('\x06','',s)) #remove all \x06 from s
print(re.sub('\x04','',s1)) #remove all \x04 from s1
```

Comment: regular expressions are overkill for this method. Just use `str.replace`

Comment: i believe that in the second print statement is should be 's1', not s