# How to remove escape characters from a string or add a list of text into one pandas column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, escaping

I did some web scraping using the code below. When i try to convert list to string it includes the escape sequences and ascii code. When i tried print it is printing properly, but I am trying to make a csv using the text hence want the escape sequence to be removed

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_link = "https://www.undercurrentnews.com/2018/08/07/ecuador-tax-reform-to-spur-more-shrimp-investment/"
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "lxml")
textContent = []
for i in range(len(page_content.find_all("p"))):
    paragraphs = page_content.find_all("p")[i].text
    textContent.append(paragraphs)
raw_text = ' '.join(textContent)
```

> 'Don\'t have an account? Sign up Enter the email address associated
>   with your account.\nWe\'ll send you instructions to reset your
>   password

when i tried printing, it shows:

> Don't have an account? Sign up Enter the email address associated with
>   your account. We'll send you instructions to reset your password.

I want to remove the \n,\xa0 etc
I tried some suggested decoding

```
decoded_string = bytes(raw_text, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
```

still the same result. 
Since this is done for huge text I am unable to use the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115261/how-to-remove-all-the-escape-sequences-from-a-list-of-strings). The text is fine when it is in list but when i convert it to string using join then these escape sequences are adding. Is there a way to add list itself to pandas ?

Comment: Could you provide the content of the list you're trying to format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all the escape sequences from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115261/how-to-remove-all-the-escape-sequences-from-a-list-of-strings) Closely related.

Comment: I tried the solution and it does not work as the text and escape sequences are larger and does not come under the proposed list. I also looking for a solution which will avoid the translation from list ot string using join